# Element border that will have transparent corners

Tags: css

I need to create a button or an element that will have border with transparent corners like in the example image.

[image: button margins have transparent corners]

I didn't find any css for this, and i was thinking to put 4 `:after` elements that will cover the corners of the element. Do you have any pure css or jquery solution for this ?

Comment: is the image the result you want to achive ?

Comment: yes, i want to know how can i make the corners transparent for different elements ... like in the example button

Comment: acually this button looks like some overlayed divs. propably its easier to use a png :) where have you found this button ? or do you just want to do some like this in css because you feel like to do it that way ?

Comment: Dwza you're not being constructive.

Comment: @ImagineStudios i know, and i didnt say "do it with png" i sayed "its propably easier" sorry for having a longer communication than expacted ill try to be short now ;)

Comment: Do you want it with 1 div ? or is it no problem to use more than 1 element ?

Comment: with background gradient and background-size, you can do this within a single element

Comment: I need the easiest way... create an example on jsfiddle so we can start from there.

Comment: GCyrillus can you create an example ?

Comment: @Alex, is this what you're trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/7trbxLnm/2/

Comment: This is also good, but if you want to add more space to the corners ?

Comment: @Alex from evan example , you can add extra space to corners adding an extra shadow : http://jsfiddle.net/GCyrillus/7trbxLnm/3/ , it needs some extra margin too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the selected answer rocks! I did this before I noticed this was answered. It uses :before and :after. It's probably legacy browser compatible -- if the browser supports pseudo elements. It's a single element too.

**http://jsbin.com/gopox/1/edit**

[image]

CSS:

```
.button {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1;
     background:#f7f7f7;
     cursor:pointer;
}
.button:before, .button:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.button:after {
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}
.button:hover:before,
.button:hover:after {
    border-color: blue;
    color:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
  <a href="http://google.com" class="button">My Button</a>

  <button class="button">My Button</button>
```

Comment: Thank you BootstrapThemer also for your time. It is good to see other version of the same result :)

Comment: Your code works also on ie9 and ie8. The fist code doesnt work bellow ie10.

Comment: Yes, I know. I tend to figure things out that will work with legacy browsers as much as possible

Answer (score 4):

Here is an **[example](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dHKhe)**, as requested,  using `background-image` (wich is a single color linear-gradient)

```
button {
  border:3px transparent solid;
  background:tomato;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
  display:inline-block;/* optionnal, it should be defaut layout */
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to left, brown, brown),
    linear-gradient(to left, brown, brown),
    linear-gradient(to left, brown, brown),
    linear-gradient(to left, brown, brown);
  background-size:
    80% 2px,
    80% 2px,
    2px 80%,
    2px 80%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:
    top, 
    bottom, 
    left, 
    right;
}
```